# Excel Range.PivotField equivalent for JavaScript API

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

In the VBA / C# API for Excel, there is the [Range.PivotField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pivotfield) property available. Is there an equivalent in the JavaScript API, or more specifically, can I find the PivotField that is bound to the active cell?

I found that there is [PivotField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotfield?view=office-js) in the JS API and these fields are contained in pivot table hierarchies, but the link to range seems to be missing. Alternatively, if there isn't Range.PivotField, could there a "PivotField.Range", that is, could I scan the pivot tables in a worksheet and create a cell-pivot field mapping?

### Update

I've managed to map the pivot table areas (rows, columns, body and filters separately) like this:

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(event.worksheetId);
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                ws.load('pivotTables');
            })
                .then(context.sync)
                .then(function () {
                    ws.pivotTables.items.forEach(function (value, index) {

                        value.load('layout');
                        value.load('name');
                        value.load('rowHierarchies');
                        value.load('columnHierarchies');
                        value.load('dataHierarchies');
                        value.load('filterHierarchies');
                        //value.context.sync().then(function () {
                        sheetPivotTables[event.worksheetId][index] = {
                            Layout: value.layout,
                            Name: value.name,
                            RowHierarchies: value.rowHierarchies,
                            ColumnHierarchies: value.columnHierarchies,
                            DataHierarchies: value.dataHierarchies,
                            FilterHierarchies: value.filterHierarchies,

                            RowRange: null,
                            ColumnRange: null,
                            DataRange: null,
                            FilterRange: null,
                            Range: null
                        };
                    });
                })
                .then(context.sync)
                .then(function () {
                    sheetPivotTables[event.worksheetId].forEach(function (item, index) {
                        var rowHierarchyCount = 0;
                        if (item.RowHierarchies != undefined) {
                            // empty row hierarchy count = 0!
                            rowHierarchyCount = item.RowHierarchies.getCount();
                        }
                        item.RowHierarchyCount = rowHierarchyCount;

                        var columnHierarchyCount = 0;
                        if (item.ColumnHierarchies != undefined) {
                            // empty column hiearchy count = 1!
                            columnHierarchyCount = item.ColumnHierarchies.getCount();
                        }
                        item.ColumnHierarchyCount = columnHierarchyCount;

                        var dataHierarchyCount = 0;
                        if (item.DataHierarchies != undefined) {
                            // empty data hiearchy count = 0!
                            dataHierarchyCount = item.DataHierarchies.getCount();
                        }
                        item.DataHierarchyCount = dataHierarchyCount;

                        var filterHierarchyCount = 0;
                        if (item.FilterHierarchies != undefined) {
                            // empty filter hiearchy count = 0!
                            filterHierarchyCount = item.FilterHierarchies.getCount();
                        }
                        item.FilterHierarchyCount = filterHierarchyCount;
                    });
                })
                .then(context.sync)
                .then(function () {
                    sheetPivotTables[event.worksheetId].forEach(function (item, index) {

                        item.Range = item.Layout.getRange();
                        item.Range.load('rowCount');
                        item.Range.load('columnCount');
                        item.Range.load('rowIndex');
                        item.Range.load('columnIndex');

                        if (item.RowHierarchyCount.m_value > 0) {
                            // empty row hierarchy count = 0!
                            item.RowRange = item.Layout.getRowLabelRange();
                            item.RowRange.load('rowCount');
                            item.RowRange.load('columnCount');
                            item.RowRange.load('rowIndex');
                            item.RowRange.load('columnIndex');
                        }

                        if (item.ColumnHierarchyCount.m_value > 1) {
                            // empty column hiearchy count = 1!
                            item.ColumnRange = item.Layout.getColumnLabelRange();
                            item.ColumnRange.load('rowCount');
                            item.ColumnRange.load('columnCount');
                            item.ColumnRange.load('rowIndex');
                            item.ColumnRange.load('columnIndex');
                        }

                        if (item.DataHierarchyCount.m_value > 0) {
                            // empty data hiearchy count = 0!
                            item.DataRange = item.Layout.getDataBodyRange();
                            item.DataRange.load('rowCount');
                            item.DataRange.load('columnCount');
                            item.DataRange.load('rowIndex');
                            item.DataRange.load('columnIndex');
                        }

                        if (item.FilterHierarchyCount.m_value > 0) {
                            // empty filter hiearchy count = 0!
                            item.FilterRange = item.Layout.getFilterAxisRange();
                            item.FilterRange.load('rowCount');
                            item.FilterRange.load('columnCount');
                            item.FilterRange.load('rowIndex');
                            item.FilterRange.load('columnIndex');
                        }
                    });
                })
                .then(context.sync);
```

It is then possible to find the selected pivot table and the selected data item in the table body (see [getDataHierarchy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=office-js#getdatahierarchy-cell-)):

```
selectedDataItem = selectedPivotTable.layout.getDataHierarchy(selectedRange);
```

The axes remain the issue. [getPivotItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=office-js#getpivotitems-axisstring--cell-) should work here, but it only seems to return a correct empty array when there are no items on the corresponding axis. Otherwise it stops the execution of the event handler at the nearest `context.sync()` call:

```
...
                    selectedPivotItems = selectedPivotTable.layout.getPivotItems("column", selectedRange);

                })
                .then(context.sync)
...
```

I reported this and it is an open bug now: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/569

Answer (score 2):

In JS API, there is a [PivotLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=office-js) which you can get ranges of the pivot table. For example, PivotTable.layout.getDataBodyRange(),PivotTable.layout.getRange().

You can get more information from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=office-js . (Please not the getCell method is not supported yet)

Comment: Thanks, this could work, using first the getRowLabelRange(), getColumnLabelRange(), getDataBodyRange() and getFilterAxisRange() to divide the pivot table into axes and then calling [getPivotItems(axisString, cell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=office-js#getpivotitems-axisstring--cell-) with the appropriate axis name to get the PivotItem.